# I cant view the images from data base in an image view

Tags: android, database, sqlite, imageview

hi i stored the images name in a database and the images are in the drwable folder and i retrive the images name into string array(imageArray[]) list so to view it in an image view i did this but its not working

```
imageview1.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt("R.drawable."+imageArray[pos]);
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to retrieve drawable.

```
String imageId=imageArray[pos];
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                      .getIdentifier(imageId, "drawable", getPackageName()));
imageview1.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```